# testing main method with jmockit

Tags: java, junit, tdd, jmockit

to get closer to 100%, I'd like to test the main method.
I only create an instance of a class, which should start
the application. Test and code looks like this:

```
public class MainTest {
    @Test
    public void delegates_to_Launcher_instance(@Mocked Launcher launcher) {
        String[] args = {"i"};
        Main.main(args);
        new Verifications() {{ launcher.run(args); }};
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Launcher().run(args);
    }
}

public class Launcher {
    public void run(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

Works perfectly!

Now, the Launcher class is a bit superfluous, and coverage is not 100%, because the constructor of Main is not called. Both could be healed by moving the code from Launcher to main, like this:

```
public class MainTest {
    @Test
    public void delegates_to_Main_instance(@Mocked Main main) {
        String[] args = {"i"};
        Main.main(args);
        new Verifications() {{ main.run(args); }};
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main().run(args);
    }
}
```

But when I do this, JMockit complains with:

```
Missing invocation to:
mmm.Main#run(["i"])
   on mock instance: mmm.Main@224aed64

    at mmm.MainTest$1.<init>(MainTest.java:15)
    at mmm.MainTest.delegates_to_Main_instance(MainTest.java:15)
Caused by: Missing invocation
    at mmm.Main.run(Main.java)
    ... 2 more
```

Can anybody explain, what's going on here?

Comment: Unrelated: read about Java naming conventions. Using _ is only for SOME_CONSTANTS - but "_" doesnt go into method names!

Comment: GhostCat's answers is correct. I will only add that the whole idea of using mocking here is bad. A good test verifies that a given class "A" solves the *meaninful business problem* it's supposed to solve, *not* that it calls some method in class "B". Also, tests should not be written to increase *code* coverage, but to increase the coverage of *business requirements*. Otherwise, you end up with a bunch of tests which not only are of little value, but also discourage you/others from creating those tests that actually matter. Mocking is only useful in special cases - beyond that it's harmful.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
public void delegates_to_Main_instance(@Mocked Main main) {
```

You are **mocking** main. At the same time you want to write a *unit test* that exercises that `main` object. That doesn't make sense. You only *mock* things that go into your production code and that you need to control/verify. You do **not** mock the object that you intend to test itself!

In your first example you are using a mocked `Launcher` which gets passed to the class under test. Makes perfect sense. In the second example, you pass a mocked instance and then assume the mocked instance is the class under test. Makes not so much sense.